# Ant design code for customization of each character in Rate component not working in typescript 4.4.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

I have a React project with Typescript 4.4.4. I am using ant design version 4.24.5 in it. I want to use the Rate component provided by ant design where I want to customize each character of the Rate Component. I am trying to use the code provided in the ant design official documentation for the Rate component where I want different character icons in a single Rate component.

Here is the code I copied from the documentation at this link https://ant.design/components/rate#components-rate-demo-character-function but it is not working in typescript:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FrownOutlined, MehOutlined, SmileOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Rate } from 'antd';

const customIcons: Record<number, React.ReactNode> = {
  1: <FrownOutlined />,
  2: <FrownOutlined />,
  3: <MehOutlined />,
  4: <SmileOutlined />,
  5: <SmileOutlined />,
};

const App: React.FC = () => (
  <>
    <Rate defaultValue={3} character={({ index }: { index: number }) => customIcons[index + 1]} />
  </>
);

export default App;
```

It is giving me the following error:

Type '({ index }: { index: number; }) => React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type '({ index }: { index: number; }) => ReactNode' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactPortal': key, children, type, props  TS2322

Can anyone help me in this regard please?

I tried different solutions trying to make the types become same but I haven't been able to figure out what the problem really is as I am fairly new to typescript.

Comment: You do not need to write type for character index. Just remove `{ index: number }`. After removing that, typescript will error `index is possibly 'undefined'.`. You can use `non-null assertion operator (!)` with index. `<Rate defaultValue={3} character={({ index }) => customIcons[index! + 1]} />`

Comment: When I removed ```{ index: number }```. Now, the error is:
```Type '({ index }: { index: any; }) => ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'```.
I even added ```non-null assertion operator (!)``` but that didn't solve the problem either.

Comment: Please specify the antd and react version you are using.

Comment: I am using antd version 4.24.5.

Comment: I was not able to produce that error using antd 4.24.5. Can you please create a code sandbox?

Comment: Maybe then there is a problem in my project.